# Android fragment didn't show using recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to create navigation drawer using RecyclerView and use fragment. The menu on navigation drawer are using RecyclerView and when menu is clicked then change to selected fragment.

I have a problem when i click a menu but fragment didn't change

below is my MainActivity.java

```
   package com.ayotong.miranda;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //First We Declare Titles And Icons For Our Navigation Drawer List View
    //This Icons And Titles Are holded in an Array as you can see

    String TITLES[] = {"Home","Events","Mail","Shop"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ic_article,R.drawable.ic_stat,R.drawable.ic_about};

    //Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header view
    //And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view

    String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
    String COND = "Healthy";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.teh;
    int lastMenu = -1;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    /* Assinging the toolbar object ot the view
    and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar
     */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);




        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,COND,PROFILE, this);       

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());

                if(child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
                    Drawer.closeDrawers();
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Item Clicked is: " + recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    onTouchDrawer(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));

                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
            }
        });


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

    }

    private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void onTouchDrawer(final int position) {

        if (lastMenu == position) return;

        switch (lastMenu = position) {
            case 1:
                openFragment(new Home_fragment());
                break;
            case 2:
                openFragment(new Stat_fragment());
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

}
```

below is Main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

below is fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HOME MIRANDA"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"-->
        <!--android:scrollbars="vertical"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"/>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

below is fragment_home.java

```
package com.ayotong.miranda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Home_fragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this so i can change fragment when menu on navigation drawer is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the openFragment() in the onItemTouchListener of the recycler view. Before loading the fragment try to close the drawer and then call the openFragment(). I think it should work. Also check whether the container id is correct.